# Ruby on rails Production mode on apache2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I am trying to switch from development mode to production my project in ruby on rails.  Do I really need to install passenger?  I have already apache server running in the system.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You need to install passenger to configure your rails app with Apache server. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) is the step by step solution for the same.